# Nasm: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, nasm, emu8086

I'm trying to put my `.asm` (version x8086) file in the `nasm` And I get

```
nums.asm:7: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
nums.asm:9: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

```
JMP MAIN
ADDRESS_MEMORY dw 0
JUMPS dw 0
DIVIDE equ 50

MAIN:
    mov ADDRESS_MEMORY, ax ; <- Error
    JMP RANDOM_NUMBER              
    mov JUMPS, cx ; <-    Error
```

What is the issue? Help. I really need to use this like that. How can I move the value to the global variables without error?

Comment: ADDRESS_MEMORY and JUMPS are both defined as dw (double-word) which is 4 bytes, while registers ax and cx are both word-size (2 bytes)

Comment: But if I change it I get an error. The d doesn't mean double

Comment: NASM syntax is different from EMU8086.  In NASM syntax, `ADDRESS_MEMORY` is an immediate constant (the address), so it can't be the destination.  You left out the [].

Comment: @KermittheFrog: No, `dw` is Data Word, 16 bits.  `dd` is 32-bit data double-word.  And NASM doesn't magically associate symbol names with sizes the way MASM/TASM and EMU8086 do.  This code is actually correct for EMU8086, missing square brackets for NASM.

Comment: @PeterCordes So ```mov [ADDRESS_MEMORY], ax``` ?

Comment: ok. sorry. i dont know much about nasm

Comment: But it will insert the address that is the value. If ADDRESS_MEMORY = 10, so it will put in address number 10 the value of ax

Comment: No, `mov [ADDRESS_MEMORY], ax` is a store, a  mov with a memory destination.  If that's not what you wanted, write `mov ax, ADDRESS_MEMORY` to put the address in AX or `mov ax, [ADDRESS_MEMORY]` to load from it.  The linked duplicate has examples.